# Multiple uneven investments - present value

Tags: excel

Let us assume that I have been investing from last few years in the following manner:

```
01-Jan-2013 - $100
12-Apr-2013 - $500
15-Dec-2013 - $400
10-Mar-2014 - $600
20-Oct-2014 - $300
```

How do I calculate what would be the total value as of today if all of these investments were to get an interest of, say, 7% compounded quarterly?

Is there a general way to calculate this using Excel?

Comment: see [Financial functions (reference)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Financial-functions-reference-5658D81E-6035-4F24-89C1-FBF124C2B1D8)

Answer (score 0):

First calculate how many months have passed since the date, then divide it into quarters and finally calculates the interest of each quarter

```
                       months 
                      to date     quarters      7%      Total 

    1-Jan-13    100     33          11          7        77
    12-Apr-13   500     29,63       9,87        35       345,72
    15-Dec-13   400     21,4        7,13        28       199,73
    10-Mar-14   600     18,56       6,18        42       259,93
    20-Oct-14   300     11,1        3,7         21       77,7
```

Comment: 7% each quarter, eg. $500 * 7% = $35 then multiply by the amount of quarters has pass, $35 * 9,87 = $345,72